# Count multiple row values in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table:

[image: Pic]

It counts for the number and year if a car was used or not based on the month. A would now write a query for a specific year like

```
> where year = 2018 (Lets pretend it now February)
```

The result I need is from 2018 backwards a car is not used. For example for 2018 it would be 3 because from now on (FEB) till Dez.2017 there are 3 following 0's. If a 1 appears -> stop counting. If I'm interested in 2017

```
> where year = 1.2017
```

it does of course not matter which month I'm in currently because 2017 is already over so it would count 1 (3 in the pic is obviously wrong)

Comment: Could you some sample data and expect result? use format text instead of image.

Answer (score 2):

select count(*) from TABLE 
where year <= 2018
and sum(monthA + monthB + monthC + ...) <= 3;

Answer (score 0):

One method is a giant `case` expression

```
select t.*,
       (case when greatest(jan, feb, . . . , dec) = 0 then 12
             when greatest(jan, feb, . . . , nov) = 0 then 11
             . . .
             when jan = 0 then 1
             else 0
        end) as result_i_need
from t;
```